# Cakephp Generating XML view files

Tags: xml, cakephp, sitemap

I'm trying to achieve [Using a data view with view files](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-a-data-view-with-view-files).

But to no luck, i'm getting below error and couldn't generate the xml.

```
<response>
<code>500</code>
<url>/photo/sitemaps/view.xml</url>
<name>Call to undefined method Xml::options()</name>
</response>
```

To access the xml, the link is similar to this: http://www.example.com/action/view.xml

My View code is:

```
// View code - app/View/Action/xml/view.ctp
$xmlObject = Xml::fromArray($xmlArray);
$xmlString = $xmlObject->asXML();
```

Though I'm not sure what should my controller looks like.

I've already enabled Router::parseExtensions().
I've also added the RequestHandlerComponent to controller’s list of components.
If my data is serialized in the controller, it's working perfectly.
Btw, I'm using Cakephp 2.3.4

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure there's no more code to show?? The error says that you're calling `Xml::options` and there's no `options` method called from the Xml class itself, so I think you are calling it somewhere and that's causing your error.

Comment: Why not leveraging the ViewClass when you are already on 2.x?

Comment: Im actually in the phase of refreshing my cakephp knowledge so please bear with me. But thank you guys so much for the quick response.

Comment: Im actually in the phase of refreshing my cakephp knowledge so please bear with me. But thank you guys so much for the quick response. My routes.php has this: `Router::parseExtensions();` My controller has these:  (controller variables) `public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form'); public $components = array('RequestHandler');`. View action: ($output is array mapped) `$this->set(array( 'xmlArray' => array('url' => $output), '_serialize' => array('xmlArray') ));`. So you see I got the serialize version working.

Comment: To use view file, i've setup the codes in `//app/View/Action/xml/view.ctp`. But I'm not sure what should my controller looks like. I've tried this: `$this->set('xmlArray', array('response' => $output));`. But i'm getting above mentioned error.